Clicking on the "follow button" in LinkedIn through Selenium and Python
I'm beginning to learn Selenium and one of the tasks to complete is to click on the "Follow" button located at the bottom of right hand side, specifically in the "About the company" section.
HTML Inspect
Once I'm logged in, I tried to find the element by using these two locators:
Locator XPATH
follow_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="main"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/section/section/div[1]/div[1]/button')
follow_button.click()

Locator CSS_SELECTOR
follow_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='.jobs-company__box div button')
follow_button.click()

or
follow_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='.jobs-company div div button')
follow_button.click()

I couldn't get the button "Follow" clicked and Python just threw me his message error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\LinkedIn\main.py", line 31, in <module>
    follow_button.click()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 94, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 395, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 347, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (910, 2211)
  (Session info: chrome=123.0.6312.105)
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7CBB17072+63090]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7CBA82CC2]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7CB91EC65]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7CB96BB34]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7CB969954]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7CB967164]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7CB965EF9]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7CB95A708]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7CB986FDA]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7CB95A00A]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7CB9871F0]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7CB9A3412]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7CB986D83]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7CB9583A8]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7CB959441]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7CBF125CD+4238285]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7CBF4F72D+4488493]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7CBF47A0F+4456463]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7CBBF05B6+953270]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7CBA8E58F]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7CBA89264]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7CBA8939B]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7CBA79BD4]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFDBC227344+20]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFDBDDA26B1+33]

However, when applying the XPATH locator to click on the "Save" button, I had no problem at all. Here's the full code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?f_LF=f_AL&geoId=102257491&keywords=python%20developer&location=London%2C%20England%2C%20United%20Kingdom&redirect=false&position=1&pageNum=0")

time.sleep(2)
sign_in = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, value="Sign in")
sign_in.click()

time.sleep(1)
user_name = driver.find_element(By.ID, value="username")
user_name.send_keys("YOUR_USERNAME")
last_name = driver.find_element(By.ID, value="password")
last_name.send_keys("YOUR_PASSWORD")
sign_in_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="form div button")
sign_in_button.click()

input("Press Enter after Captcha is finished")

time.sleep(2)
save_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="main"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div/button/span[1]')
save_button.click()

time.sleep(2)
**follow_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="main"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/section/section/div[1]/div[1]/button/span')
follow_button.click()**

Screenshot of the element I want to get:
enter image description here
Any suggestion is highly appreciated.
Thanks

I don't see how that code could cause a stale element exception.  Please post the full code and the full exception traceback message.

If the exact position of the button is static, consider finding the screen coordinates and clicking the button with the mouse using pyautogui.

Can you provide a screenshot of which element you're trying to get? and full code as well

@AhmedI.Elsayed I just edited the question, you should see the screenshot at the end.

One of the reasons you get ElementClickInterceptedException could be that the Follow button isn't in the viewport when you try to click it. The element isn't visible before scrolling down.
As I can see, the Saved button is at the top of the page, which means, it is always in the viewport, but for the Follow button, have you scrolled down?
It is hard to be sure from the picture you posted whether or not have you scrolled, so consider my answer depending on your scenario.
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/wheel/#scroll-to-element

Idk why you're getting this error, but your selector looks like it does change  by SSR, if they modify anything in LinkedIn's source
here's a version that would work much better and probabl:
Enter this in your chrome console, while on a job's page
$x("//button[.//text()='Follow']")

Notes:

$x is a function in developer tools console, it's only available in browsers, it queries by XPATH.
text() returns the inner text of the selected element, button
.//text() dives to check if the innerText is not in the button itself, but its children

using this xpath
//button[.//text()='Follow']

Will query the button correctly, if you want a faster query, query the right side (job description section), then query by xpath inside it to get the button, more hacks are there to improve performance, but get it working first
Notes on Selenium:

Selenium doesn't send many headers by default, the Selenium app is most likely opening a LinkedIn that's not the one available in your country, which means the source code is totally different, to get sure of this, open LinkedIn in the driver and add something like sleep(900000) to read the code.
To solve this, you'll need to emulate the real request that gets sent from your chrome (normal chrome) in the driver, so everything works as expected.
This may cause unexpected behavior, sometimes, a popup or an overlay may be covering your button, which I assume is the case, don't run a headless selenium, check the browser and the source code in case of any overlays show up, some websites show overlays as a first measure against bots, it usually disables some bots, specially if the overlay selectors change each time

